# Object of class Zend_Db_Table_Row could not be converted to string

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I get the error message in the title when I run the following:

```
$year = date('Y');
        $month = date('n');
        $day = date('j') - 3;
        $week = date('W') - 1;

        $select = "SELECT IF( station_name =  '',  'Unknown', station_name ) station_name, station_name as db_name, sum(case when year(print_date) = $year then print_pages end) as yearpages, sum(case when (month(print_date) = $month and year(print_date) = $year) then print_pages end) as monthpages, sum(case when (day(print_date) = $day and year(print_date) = $year and month(print_date) = $month) then print_pages end) as daypages, sum(case when (week(print_date) = $week AND year(print_date) = $year AND month(print_date) = $month) then print_pages end) as weekpages
                    FROM `file_prints`
                    GROUP BY station_name;";

        $rows = $_userTable->getAdapter()->fetchAll($select);
        foreach($rows as $key => $row)
        {
            $oModelStation = new Application_Model_PrintStation();
            $fPrintsModel = new Application_Model_FilePrints();
            $station = $oModelStation->fetchRow($oModelStation->select()->where('name = ?', $row['station_name']));
            $row['weekpages'] = $fPrintsModel->fetchRow($fPrintsModel
                ->select(array('sum(print_pages) as weekpages'))
                ->where('station_name = ?', $row['station_name']));
                ->where('year(print_date) = ?', $year)
                ->where('week(print_date) = ?', $week));

            echo $row['weekpages'];
```

The error is traced back to the final line is this sample code (echo $row['weekpages']). I've tested the results through echoes of the initial $select SQL query and it seems satisfactory, and I've tried removing various where conditions in the fetchRow execution to see if one condition is to blame but I keep getting the same error message.

Also, when I do a var_dump($row) using this code, I see that the key for weekpages points to a Zend objects whereas all of the other keys for daypages, monthpages, and yearpages point to strings containing numeric values.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `$row = $fPrintsModel->fetchRow(...)` and then you access `$row['weekpages']` later? I haven't used Zend Framework myself, but it looks like `fetchRow` returns an object which you can't just echo out.

Comment: I can find no reference to a `fetchRow()` method in a grep of the `\Zend\Db` code. It must be a method that you have added to the `FilePrints` model. As observed above by @Joel, `fetchRow()` appears to return an object that can't automatically cast to string when used in an `echo()`. Perhaps add a `__toString()` method to that object? Also, it seems that you are expecting `$row['weekday']` to contain a scalar value. One would expect a method named `fetchRow()` to give an array/object/row, not a single scalar/string/int, right?

Comment: @DavidWeinraub Wouldn't this be it? http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.table.row.html

Comment: @JoelHinz: D'oh! I'm a dolt. I was grepping ZF2 code base. Sorry...

Comment: What does your `Application_Model_FilePrints` class look like?

Comment: @Kevin Nagurski <?php

class Application_Model_FilePrints extends Application_Model_Abstract 
{
    protected $_name = 'file_prints';
 protected $_primary = 'id';
} //that's the extent of the file

Comment: What does `Application_Model_Abstract` look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is telling you what the problem is.  fetchRow() is returning a Zend_Db_Table_Row object which you are then storing in an array in the index 'weekpages'.  I'm not sure what you intend to do with the data from the retrieved row but you can try either converting the row object into an array with ->toArray() or accessing individual fields of the row object like this:

```
echo $row['weekpages']->weekpages;
```

That's assuming you intended for $row['weekpages'] to hold the row object although your choice of string for the index makes me think that might not be the case.

For extra clarification, the value of $row['weekpages'] is the row object and the column you have aliased in your query is also called "weekpages".